# Generic function for two List<>

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have two List<> with the same field that I need to edit. How to write a common function for these lists?

```
public List<?> CutField(List<?> list)
{
    foreach(var element in list)
    {
        element.Field = // ;
    }
    return List<?>;
}
```

Comment: Do these two types implement the same interface, specifying the property? (You really don't want to be exposing the field publicly anyway...) Also, why return the list, given that you're just modifying the objects that the list elements refer to?

Comment: Let those two types implement the same interface and declare the list as `List<interfacetype>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Or have a generic method with a type constraint on the type parameter - that would be more flexible.

Comment: How do you know `element.Field` exists?

Comment: Why would you want to write a common function for two different entities? Sounds like bad design and you need to back up a step to see what you can improve instead. Remember the [Rule of Three](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/10/31/abstraction-the-rule-of-three/) - it seems like your function would not be re-usable for three, four or more objects, so you should consider a different option.

Comment: Jack, please provide a [mcve] and both your types that your lists have items from, so we can help you. You're not providing enough information as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be using generics:

```
public List<T> CutField<T>(List<T> list) where T : MyInterface
{
    foreach(T element in list)
    {
        element.Field = // ;
    }

    return list;
}
```

With

```
public interface MyInterface 
{ 
    object Field { get; set; } // or whatever datatype you need for the field
}
```

Of course all the possible types within your list should implement that interface.

As an aside you can also omit the return-type from `CutField`, as you´re already modifying the list passed as parameter.

Comment: Hi. I wrote it , But  T is red and VS write me: cfnnjt resolve symbol T and where is red : Constrains are not allowed on non-generic declaration

Comment: yes, now its working! But now hows can I pass my two List in this generic?

Comment: You need to create a new `List<MyInterface>` and put your instances into it.

Comment: And MyInterface must contain all of the properties my List<>?

Comment: No, just those which you want to access within your method.

Comment: OK, for example I have List<Posts> and List<News> .They have Title property . And I need to change this property.  And I Create  List<MyInterface> list = ??

Comment: When both `Post` and `News` implement `MyInterface` (which they *have to*) you can simply copy the elements from the lists into the new one, e.g. using a loop.